# In my Unity I am using OnTriggerEnter2D for collision for a bullet and plane but the result I am inputing in the condition occurs once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

In the following code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public int coins;
    void Start()
    {
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 8f);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Plane"))
        {
            coins += 5;
        }
    }
}
```

in the OnTriggerEnter2D function I compare the bullet and the plane but the coins only increase by 5 once. So if the bullet and the plane collides again it is still 5 and yes I have assigned the tags.

I tried putting the same result to other objects like the plane and player but the same result occured.

Answer (score 0):

`OnTriggerEnder2D` is triggered at the trigger moment. meaning, if the bullet never left the plane collider it won't count as another collision. Make sure the bullet leaves the plane collider for that to work multiple times

Comment: The moment the plane is hit by the bullet the plane is set active to false. Also is the bullet and plane being a object a problem?

Comment: Please add all of the relevant code snippets to the question. If you disable the plane I assume you re-enable it later (otherwise there can't be another collision)? Also, everything is an object so I don't understand your question.